# How to limit keypress eventlistener to a single component?

Tags: reactjs, event-listener

I have a custom select component. I want to add keyboard navigation (navigating options with arrows keys and select one with "enter"). Usually, those event listeners are attached to the window. But what if I have two select on the same page? Pressing arrow down would trigger an action in both components.

How would you modify this code to make sure it remains within the scope of each Select?

```js
React.useEffect(() => {
     window.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeyDown);
      // do stuff
    });
    
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('keydown', handleKeyDown);
    };
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to listen the event on window globally you can check `target` property of the event:

```
function Element(props) {
    
    const element = useRef(null);

    function handleKeyDown(event) {
        if(event.target === element.current) {
            //do stuff
        }        
    }

    useEffect(()=> {
        window.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeyDown);
    
        return ()=> {
            window.removeEventListener('keydown', handleKeyDown);
        };
    }, [])

    return <div ref={element}>
        // element content
    </div>
    
}
```

But maybe it would be better to listen the event on a local element:

```
function Element(props) {
    
    const element = useRef(null);

    function handleKeyDown(event) {
        //do stuff
    }

    useEffect(()=> {
        if(element.current) {
            element.current.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeyDown);
            return ()=> {
                element.current.removeEventListener('keydown', handleKeyDown);
            };
        }
    }, [])

    return <div ref={element}>
        // element content
    </div>
    
}
```